# Неверная кодировка кириллицы в Native messaging chrome extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, chrome-extension

Переписываю с С на Python 3.11 расширение для хрома (chrome.extension). Использую Native messaging. Так вот, при получении ответа, кириллица отображается как ������. При этом, если скрипт питона вызывать из консоли, то отображается нормально; в оригинале на C всё нормально. Куда копать?

Отправляю так:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('I', len(msg)))
sys.stdout.write(msg)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Пробовал переводить `stdout` в бинарный режим, но результат тот же.

Comment: Что в msg и какая операционная система? https://ibb.co/4jDg04Q

Comment: В msg, кирилическая строка, windows 10